# Why is my GUISkin Button onActive not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I implemented a GUI Skin to my script. Although in button options, I implement a texture to onActive background texture, it did not work. Except this, all of the changes are working inside GUI Skin. The texture which I used in onActive texture type is Sprite(2D and UI). You may see how I implement in the onGUI() method in the script to the following code.

```cs
//...
public GUISkin mySkin;
//...
private void OnGUI()
{
     //... 
     GUI.skin = mySkin;

     turkishButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClickLanguageEvent.Add(1));
     englishButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClickLanguageEvent.Add(2));
     latinButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClickLanguageEvent.Add(3));

     Vector3 scale = new Vector3(Screen.width / nativeSize.x, Screen.height / nativeSize.y, 1.0f);
     GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, scale);

     float spacing = 30;
     float x = 7 + spacing;
     float y = 63;
     //...
}
```

No matter how much I researched the cause of the problem, I could not find it. If it helps, I can throw out any part of the code.

[image: This is my Treeview GUISKin]

[image: this is how I assign to my script]

[image: this is the button before I click]

[image: this is the button after I click]

As seen from the pictures, although I added a blue texture to the background of "onActive", nothing changed when I clicked.

Comment: `I can throw out any part of the code` I would suggest starting with where and how you configured the `mySkin` and maybe a description and screenshots of how it should look like and what happens instead ;)

Comment: Updating my question with screenshots